# .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] at route.(anonymous function) as get[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, mean-stack

Hi every one I got this error in server.js there is no such error as I am beginner in this so I tried to read many answers on stackover flow but I didnt get answer. So can kindly some one edit this code or tell me what is problem please ?[Error is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTaRN.png)

**Index.js**

```js
'use strict';

var controller = require('./look.controller');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = require('../../auth/auth.service');

router.post('/scrapeUpload', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.scrapeUpload);
router.post('/upload', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.upload);

router.put('/:id', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.update);

router.get('/getAllLooks', controller.allLooks);
router.get('/getUserLooks', controller.userLooks);
router.get('/:lookId', controller.singleLook);
router.get('/popLooks/:id', controller.popLooks);

router.delete('/:id', controller.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

**Route.js**

```js
/*!
 * express
 * Copyright(c) 2009-2013 TJ Holowaychuk
 * Copyright(c) 2013 Roman Shtylman
 * Copyright(c) 2014-2015 Douglas Christopher Wilson
 * MIT Licensed
 */

'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 * @private
 */

var debug = require('debug')('express:router:route');
var flatten = require('array-flatten');
var Layer = require('./layer');
var methods = require('methods');

/**
 * Module variables.
 * @private
 */

var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

/**
 * Module exports.
 * @public
 */

module.exports = Route;

/**
 * Initialize `Route` with the given `path`,
 *
 * @param {String} path
 * @public
 */

function Route(path) {
  this.path = path;
  this.stack = [];

  debug('new %s', path);

  // route handlers for various http methods
  this.methods = {};
}

/**
 * Determine if the route handles a given method.
 * @private
 */

Route.prototype._handles_method = function _handles_method(method) {
  if (this.methods._all) {
    return true;
  }

  var name = method.toLowerCase();

  if (name === 'head' && !this.methods['head']) {
    name = 'get';
  }

  return Boolean(this.methods[name]);
};

/**
 * @return {Array} supported HTTP methods
 * @private
 */

Route.prototype._options = function _options() {
  var methods = Object.keys(this.methods);

  // append automatic head
  if (this.methods.get && !this.methods.head) {
    methods.push('head');
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    // make upper case
    methods[i] = methods[i].toUpperCase();
  }

  return methods;
};

/**
 * dispatch req, res into this route
 * @private
 */

Route.prototype.dispatch = function dispatch(req, res, done) {
  var idx = 0;
  var stack = this.stack;
  if (stack.length === 0) {
    return done();
  }

  var method = req.method.toLowerCase();
  if (method === 'head' && !this.methods['head']) {
    method = 'get';
  }

  req.route = this;

  next();

  function next(err) {
    if (err && err === 'route') {
      return done();
    }

    var layer = stack[idx++];
    if (!layer) {
      return done(err);
    }

    if (layer.method && layer.method !== method) {
      return next(err);
    }

    if (err) {
      layer.handle_error(err, req, res, next);
    } else {
      layer.handle_request(req, res, next);
    }
  }
};

/**
 * Add a handler for all HTTP verbs to this route.
 *
 * Behaves just like middleware and can respond or call `next`
 * to continue processing.
 *
 * You can use multiple `.all` call to add multiple handlers.
 *
 *   function check_something(req, res, next){
 *     next();
 *   };
 *
 *   function validate_user(req, res, next){
 *     next();
 *   };
 *
 *   route
 *   .all(validate_user)
 *   .all(check_something)
 *   .get(function(req, res, next){
 *     res.send('hello world');
 *   });
 *
 * @param {function} handler
 * @return {Route} for chaining
 * @api public
 */

Route.prototype.all = function all() {
  var handles = flatten(slice.call(arguments));

  for (var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) {
    var handle = handles[i];

    if (typeof handle !== 'function') {
      var type = toString.call(handle);
      var msg = 'Route.all() requires callback functions but got a ' + type;
      throw new TypeError(msg);
    }

    var layer = Layer('/', {}, handle);
    layer.method = undefined;

    this.methods._all = true;
    this.stack.push(layer);
  }

  return this;
};

methods.forEach(function(method){
  Route.prototype[method] = function(){
    var handles = flatten(slice.call(arguments));

    for (var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) {
      var handle = handles[i];

      if (typeof handle !== 'function') {
        var type = toString.call(handle);
        var msg = 'Route.' + method + '() requires callback functions but got a ' + type;
        throw new Error(msg);
      }

      debug('%s %s', method, this.path);

      var layer = Layer('/', {}, handle);
      layer.method = method;

      this.methods[method] = true;
      this.stack.push(layer);
    }

    return this;
  };
});
```

**look.controller**

```js
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var Look = require('./look.model');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var utils = require('../../utils/utils.js');

exports.allLooks = function(req, res) {
  Look.find({})
    .sort({
      createTime: -1
    })
    .exec(function(err, looks) {
      if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
      }
      if (!looks) {
        return res.send(404);
      }
      console.log(looks);
      return res.status(200)
                     .json(looks);
    });
};

exports.userLooks = function(req, res) {
  var userEmail = req.query.email;
  Look.find({
    email: {
      $in: userEmail
    }
  })
  .sort({
    createTime: -1
  })
  .exec(function(err, looks) {
    if(err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    }
    console.log(looks);
    return res.status(200)
                   .json(looks);
  });
};

exports.scrapeUpload = function(req, res) {
  var random = utils.randomizer(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

  utils.downloadURI(req.body.image, '../client/assets/images/uploads/' + random + '.png', function(filename) {
    console.log('done');

    var newLook = new Look();
    newLook.title = req.body.title;
    newLook.image = filename.slice(9);
    newLook.email = req.body.email;
    newLook.linkURL = req.body.linkURL;
    newLook.description = req.body.description;
    newLook.userName = req.body.name;
    newLook._creator = req.body._creator;
    newLook.createTime = Date.now();
    newLook.upVotes = 0;
    newLook.save(function(err, item) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error occured in saving post');
      } else {
        console.log('Success post saved');
        console.log(item);
        res.status(200)
          .json(item);
      }
    });
  });
}

exports.upload = function(req, res) {
  var newLook = new Look();
  var fileimage = req.middlewareStorage.fileimage;

  console.log(req.body);
  newLook.image = '/assets/images/uploads/' + fileimage;
  newLook.email = req.body.email;
  newLook.linkURL = req.body.linkURL;
  newLook.title = req.body.title;
  newLook.description = req.body.description;
  newLook.userName = req.body.name;
  newLook._creator = req.body._creator;
  newLook.createTime = Date.now();
  newLook.upVotes = 0;

  newLook.save(function(err, look) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('error saving look');
      return res.send(500);
    } else {
      console.log(look);
      res.status(200)
           .send(look);
    }
  });
};

exports.singleLook = function(req, res) {
  Look.findById(req.params.lookId, function(err, look) {
    if(err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    }
    if(!look) {
      return res.send(404);
    }
    return res.json(look);
  });
};

exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) {
    delete req.body._id;
  }
  Look.findById(req.params.id, function(err, look) {
    if(err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
      }
      if(!look) {
        return res.send(404);
      }
      var updated = _.merge(look, req.body);
      updated.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
          return handleError(res, err);
        }
        console.log(look);
        return res.json(look);
      });
  });
};

exports.delete = function(req, res) {
  Look.findById(req.params.id, function(err, look) {
    if(err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    }
    if(!look) {
      return res.send(404);
    }
    look.remove(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
      }
      return res.send(200);
    });
  });
};

function handleError(res, err) {
  return res.send(500, err);
}
```

Comment: Hypothesis: one of the `controller.popLooks_or_whatever` properties evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: I didnt get as I mentioned I am beginner . Can you correct it please ?

Comment: I suspect the error is being triggered by the equivalent of `router.get('/someroute', undefined);`. This could happen if one of the controller methods (eg. `popLooks`) does not exist or has a different name than used; it would make `controller.popLooks` -> `undefined`, instead of to a controller (callback) function. The question should probably contain the `look.controller.js` as well.

Comment: I uploaded file of look.controller.js .Kindly check it please

Comment: Please [re]read my previous comment. And mail me a cookie. Nom nom.

Comment: I didnt get where is problem brother.

Comment: Got this in Index.js =  " router.get('/popLooks/:id', controller.popLooks); "  now what I should do ?

Comment: i got where is problem but How can I fix it brother ?

Comment: Add the correct method; or, if it won't be created, don't try to route to it. Pigs don't have wings.

Comment: Got this and solved this Thank you thank you so much brother . Stay blessed . Method was undefined and I just made it comment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `router.get('/popLooks/:id', controller.popLooks);`

`controller.popLooks` is not defined, so it is evaluated as `[Object undefined]`.

Define `exports.popLooks` in `look.controller` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a function definition in `look.controller`. Paste that file please.  Also note the stack trace shows the problem is line 16 of index.js.

Comment: uploaded in question . Check please

Comment: As user2864740 said missing popLooks